# Split String and Remove Commas Stored in Array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, split

I'm trying to split a string by removing parts that I do not currently need. I have removed the majority of the parts, but the output has too many commas in the array where they are being stored. Here is my current code:

```
List<String> flightItems = new ArrayList<String>();
String s = flightInfo;
String[] tokens = s.split("Start Location: | ---- |Destination: |Date/Time: ");

for (String t : tokens) {

    flightItems.add(t);
}
System.out.println(flightItems);
```

This is how the output looks currently in my console:

```
[, BOS, , ALB, , 03-20-2020 09:00AM]
```

The desired output I am looking for is this, so I can reference the indexes later:

```
[BOS, ALB, 03-20-2020 09:00AM]
```

The flightInfo string is as follows:

```
Start Location: BOS ---- Destination: ALB ---- Date/Time: 03-20-2020 09:00AM
```

Comment: `if (!t.isBlank()) { filghtItems.add(t); }` ? (older Java use `t.trim().isEmpty()` in place of `t.isBlank()`)

Answer (score 0):

While your current regex might not be ideal for splitting, it is close to doing a regex match against the input text.  Consider:

```
String input = "Start Location: BOS ---- Destination: ALB ---- Date/Time: 03-20-2020 09:00AM";
String pattern = "(?:\\b(?:Start Location:|Destination:)\\s*(\\S+)|Date/Time:\\s*(\\S+\\s+\\S+))";
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(!Objects.isNull(m.group(1)) ? m.group(1) : m.group(2));
}
System.out.println(String.join(",", matches)));
```

This prints:

```
BOS,ALB,03-20-2020 09:00AM
```